# What versions of java and javac should I have after installing latest JDK on Linux?

Tags: java, linux, javac

I've downloaded the latest JDK from oracle on a linux box.

http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/10.0.1+10/fb4372174a714e6b8c52526dc134031e/jdk-10.0.1_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz

I've unpacked the file.

After doing so, it says my java -version is 10.0.1 but my javac -version is 1.7 something.  How can I update the javac version to match the java version?

```
echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/jdk-10.0.1/bin:/opt/jdk-10.0.1/jre/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin
[ec2-user@ip ~]$ which java
/usr/bin/java
[ec2-user@ip- ~]$ which javac
/usr/bin/javac
[ec2-user@ip- ~]$
```

Comment: Most likely your `PATH` environment variable includes a jdk7 too. `which java` and `which javac` will give you a hint on what to fix.

Comment: I will look into the PATH variable, thanks Tamas.

Comment: This question pertains to Linux, so I don’t believe it’s a duplicate.

Comment: echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/jdk-10.0.1/bin:/opt/jdk-10.0.1/jre/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-29-207 ~]$ which java
/usr/bin/java
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-29-207 ~]$ which javac
/usr/bin/javac
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-29-207 ~]$

Comment: What does `ls -l /usr/bin/java` and `ls -l /usr/bin/javac` give you? In some linux distros like debian (ubuntu, mint) they are symbolic links. Usually you don't need to change them manually. There is even a command for that. I just don't remember which command.

Comment: Btw, this question looks rather a question for https://superuser.com/ or https://askubuntu.com/ than Stack Overflow.